# Login page in php and editing

Tags: php, mysql

i want to create a login page, display the data from database of particular user in table form upto 4 columns and 1 row and also should be able to update the table data's and then logout. can anyone help me in this with a script. i need it to be done using php, mysql. i have tried till this, but i don't know what to do beyond this.

```
<html>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><p>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><p>
              <input type="submit" value="Log in!" >
</form>
```

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password) 
{
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Couldn't connect to the database!");
    mysql_select_db("login") or die("Couldn't find database");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows!==0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
        {
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password']; # code...
        }

        if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
        {
            echo "You are logged in!";# 
            @$_SESSION['usernme'] = $username;
        }
        else
            echo "Your password is incorrect!";
    # code...
    }
    else
        die("That user doesn't exists!");

}
else
    die("Please enter a username and password!")
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_connect` <-- Please ***don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` extension. It has been removed from PHP*** use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead

Comment: put the `if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)` inside your `while` loop for one thing. For another thing, do NOT use this code or any part of it; it's totally unsafe.

Comment: Some comments: 1. NEVER Store passwords in a DB unhashed(&salted). 2. Do not use MYSQL, use PDO or be wide open for SQL injections. 3. don't give end users too much information about users in the DB via the errors you Echo out (could be used for brute forcing attacks)  4. Learn PHP, HTML, Mysql, javascript, etc

Comment: There's also no code to support UPDATE'ing making this question "too broad". Read the manual on that http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: No response in comments; then respond to the answer given. I'll pass on this one, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly let MySQL check if the combination of username and password is correct?

`$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "' AND password = '" . $password . "'");`

Only if `mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1`, there is a valid login. More than 1 row should not be possible.

Comment: what difference would that possibly make? `'$var'` and `'".$var."'` both do the same thing. Plus, the rest of their query is ok. One should match.

Comment: What I meant was letting MySQL do the job of checking the combination of username and password. The quotes thing is just my habit of escaping variables from strings. ;-)

Comment: Talking from experience here: answering too broad/unclear questions have a tendancy to open up a big can of worms and also risk being chased down a deep rabbit hole; I wish you well with this, really.

Comment: You're answering too, my friend. ;-)